# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [400] vs. [50]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm fairly new to tensorflow. I've build a multilayer CNN for binary classification
This is code I've done so far

```
# First Layer
W_conv1 = weight_variable([11, 11, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,64,64,1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
print(h_conv1.shape)
print(h_pool1.shape)
# Second Layer
W_conv2 = weight_variable([7, 7, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
print(h_conv2.shape)
print(h_pool2.shape)
#Third Layer 
W_conv3 = weight_variable([5, 5, 64, 128])
b_conv3 = bias_variable([128])

h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3)
print(h_conv3.shape)
print(h_pool3.shape)
# Fourth Layer
W_conv4 = weight_variable([3, 3, 128, 64])
b_conv4 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool3, W_conv4) + b_conv4)
h_pool4 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv4)
print(h_conv4.shape)
print(h_pool4.shape)
#Fifth Layer
W_conv5 = weight_variable([2, 2, 64, 32])
b_conv5 = bias_variable([32])

h_conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool4, W_conv5) + b_conv5)
h_pool5 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv5)
print(h_conv5.shape)
print(h_pool5.shape)
# Densely Connected Layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([2 * 2 * 32, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool4, [-1, 2*2*32])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
print(h_pool2_flat.shape)
print(h_fc1.shape)
```

The output of the following piece of code is -

```
(?, 64, 64, 32)
(?, 32, 32, 32)
(?, 32, 32, 64)
(?, 16, 16, 64)
(?, 16, 16, 128)
(?, 8, 8, 128)
(?, 8, 8, 64)
(?, 4, 4, 64)
(?, 4, 4, 32)
(?, 2, 2, 32)
(?, 256)
(?, 1024)
```

When I run the program I'm getting the following error

> ---
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [400] vs. [50]
>        [[Node: Equal_4 = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ArgMax_8, ArgMax_9)]]

The traceback is really long , i hope that only last few lines help

I tried running the network by changing the architecture, only time it runs properly is when there are only two convolutional layer. I'm wrote the code referencing this page https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/get_started/mnist/pros

The weight,bias,maxpooling and con2d values is as same as the ones in the link

Comment: Just do some debugging and print out the shapes of the tensors in each step. There is a step where you expect to have a 50 size tensor and get a 1600 size tensor.

Comment: I've noticed while debugging that the expected shape in the error is always 32 times the batch_size.

Comment: I tried printing the tensors at each step like you said, but none of them has the shape 1600

Comment: What about shape 50?

Comment: 50 is the batch size, so it varies as i change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error by changing values in fully connected layer

This the edited piece of code

```
# Densely Connected Layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([2 * 2 * 128, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool4, [-1, 2*2*128])   
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
```